# Is this a memory leak in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

```
int someFunction (CLLocation *currentLocation) {
  double latitude = 12.3f;
  double longitude = 22.5f;
  CLLocationDistance d1 = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:
   [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude]];
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Objective-C's memory management can seem complicated, but remembering one fundamental rule will take you far:

> You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message. You are responsible for relinquishing ownership of objects you own using release or autorelease. Any other time you receive an object, you must not release it.

You call `alloc` without a `release` or `autorelease`, so you are breaking the rule.

Comment: Thanks. Are @"Fsfsdfsd" constants handled differently ?

Comment: You don't need to worry about string constants.  You don't `alloc` them -- they are always there, regardless of how many times they have been retained or released.  (But it is still a good idea to do the right thing with any `NSString` variables you use, in case someday you put something there that is not a constant.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You are allocating a second `CLLocation` to pass to `distanceFromLocation` and not releasing it.

You could instead do:

```
CLLocationDistance d1 = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:
  [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude] autorelease]];
```

(Or various other things. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), as @whisty suggests in the comments.)

(Also, it seems a bit pointless to make the call and assign its value to `d1` and then just throw that away.)

Comment: You should probably also read apple's docs on memory management - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You alloc a CLLocation object but never release it. I'd strongly recommend reading through the the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).